# Read 'Rebind' Packet after stream resumption in SMACK with EJABBERD-BUSINESS Edition

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I wanted to read the response of **rebind** packet i sent to **ejabberd-business** edition server. Smack library prints my packets in logs but I don't understand how will I get that packet in my application like i do get others in `processPacket`.

Checking the code of SMACK, it fails in `XMPPTCPConnection->parsePackets()`. Since parsePackets only checks some specific tags e.g "message","iq","presence" etc. While my packet starts with "rebind".

I need to be able to receive this packet because if rebind is not successfull, then I should start the login process.

So, Do i need to make changes in Smack library code? or is there any way to handle this without recompiling **SMACK**?

Packet I am trying to read:

```
<rebind xmlns='my:namespace:rebind'/>
```

Comment: You really  should not invent new top level stream events. What does your 'rebind' do that you can't achieve with standard XMPP?

Comment: sorry, m editing my question now, its a business edition ejabberd server, so I am using its stream resumption feature.

Comment: And you can't use Stream Management (XEP-0198) which is supported by Smack because?

Comment: Its a custom module of business edition.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Ejabberd Business Edition (eBE) does implement a custom 'rebind' feature similar the 'resume' one from Session Management (anyway, ejabberd supports XEP-0198).

I just wrote [a small patch](https://github.com/processone/Smack/commit/2347232d89dd1f814aa22a6d03adf7d5423b7e19) that adds this functionality to Smack 4.2.0 (master branch at this moment of writing). Hope it is helpful for your client development. Please take into account that you should reuse your Smack xmpp tcp connection for this feature to be effective.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I did same kind of thing on original SMACK-4.1.6 code since we were using that. Will it be ok to use processone fork?

Comment: Yes, we will add more features from eBE on it.

Comment: so basically i have to build the SMACK library and place jars in libs folder, which i did previously, but couldn't pass this runtime error: VerifyError.. "https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/55269" to be precise. Can you please confirm which jars i need?

Comment: After rebinding, creating IQ packet is giving an exception. conn.getUser() in IQReplyFilter class is giving null.. and following exception: "Must have a local (user) JID set. Either you didn't configure one or you where not connected at least once"